# Eclipse crashes : "An error has occurred. See the log file"

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

When I start eclipse it crashes with the following message.

```
An error has occurred.  See the log file
/home/binoy/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration/1339005865980.log
```

Here's `1339005865980.log` :

```
$ cat /home/binoy/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration/1339005865980.log
!SESSION Wed Jun 06 23:34:25 IST 2012 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2012-06-06 23:34:25.991
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.InternalError: internal error: SHA-1 not available.
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.init(SecureRandom.java:105)
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:84)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.getDefaultPRNG(SecureRandom.java:186)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:150)
    at java.io.File$LazyInitialization.<clinit>(File.java:1681)
    at java.io.File.generateFile(File.java:1694)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1803)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.canWrite(Main.java:1290)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.checkConfigurationLocation(Main.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

What is the problem here? Any idea? I'm USING Ubuntu 12.04, and OpenJDK 1.7.0.

Comment: You say, you are using, `OpenJDK 1.7.0`, but security file path points to `jdk 1.6`. So, check if the `jdk 1.7` security file is also present. Generally this error occurs, if the installation is not completed successfully. So, I would say re-install jdk.

Comment: Don't just downvote, please tell me what's wrong with the question.

Comment: SO is for programming questions. This is a problem with software. Try http://superuser.com/ instead.

Comment: I wonder why SO even have eclise and ide tags.

Comment: @Chandra you should claim the bounty on this.

Comment: @BinoyBabu I guess my suggestion helped you to resolve the issue. Can you credit the bounty to my account?

Comment: @Chandra How can I do that? I don't see an option.

Comment: @BinoyBabu I think the bounty is expired. So, I guess it will be auto awarded, but only half or you need to award another bounty which should be higher than previous one, as per this thread. [How do I give someone remaining reputation points after bounty has expired?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134944/how-do-i-give-someone-remaining-reputation-points-after-bounty-has-expired). BTW, don't worry about it, leave it. Let us use SO to help each other than worry too much about points.

Comment: @Chandra I thought it was only possible to award bounty to an answer.

Comment: @Chandra in the future post your answers as answers instead of comments. You can't award points to comments...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it by uninstalling and re-installing OpenJDK.

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-6-jre
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

Comment: I don't see how there is anything wrong with your question